# Getting exception from where I did not changed the code

Tags: ios, exception, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to create a view that has many features, but I am getting an exception from this line in my code,

```
[addedList addObject:name];
```

Exception,

```
[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 1'
```

I can add my code here if required. I am not able to figure out the problem. What could be the issue causing this exception?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems like you are adding a `nil` object to your `NSMutableArray`

So, put condition such like

```
if (name != nil) {
     [addedList addObject: name];
```

And Check it Now;

Comment: but i have nothing added related to it and my code has started not to work? i need to understand the reason